# Need advice. Painted over semi-gloss wall with matt emulsion paint without primer beforehand

Tags: walls, painting, paint, repainting, primer

The painter I hired painted over the semi-gloss walls with matt emulsion paint without using a primer beforehand. So the color from the original semi gloss paint is still coming through in spots as the new paint didn't adhere properly. What would be the best step forward? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Primer and repaint. Which reminds me [of a joke](http://christianfunnypictures.com/2018/04/a-classic-church-joke-about-randy-the-painter.html)

Comment: grab that painter